# Effect on close for jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the following code for managing the jQuery UI dialog:

```
$("#mydialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      title: "myDialog",
      modal: true,
      width: "800",
      hide: null,
      open: function(event, ui){  
        //some code
    },
     close: function(event, ui){ 
        $("#mydialog").dialog("option", "fade", null);       
    }
});
```

And then I open the dialog calling this code:

```
$("#mydialog").dialog("option", {
    modal: true
}).dialog("open");
```

This works fine, but I can't see any effect when I close the dialog.

How modify my code in order to obtain this result?

Comment: What effect do you want to see?

Comment: fade effect for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want your dialog to close with a fading effect.

```
    $("#mydialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "myDialog",
    modal: true,
    width: "800",
    hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 200 } //put the fade effect
});
```

Comment: I have already tried what you are suggesting, but no effect is performed

Comment: @Joseph82 which version of jquery you are using, can you replicate the issue in a fiddle? According to my demo sample in the answer it should work.

Comment: I have edited my answer, this code works i have tested it. I removed the close and open method because they were generating an error. I don't think that you need them since in your question they're empty.

Comment: Correction the Open/Close sections don't give errors. Just redundant. @PSL's answer is also correct. Try checking your code again.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to have dialog actually close after fading process finishes, not before it.

Try closing dialog using this code, it should do the trick:

```
$("#mydialog").fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
  $("#mydialog").dialog('close');
});
```